# Can't connect to SSH with new user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I created a new user, `test`. I have done the following to the account:

- I've given `test` sudo permission
- I've added `test` to `AllowUsers` in `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- I've generated a new SSH key pair, created and pasted the key to `/home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys` (for root, I put them in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, so I'm not sure if this was wrong)
- I've check the permissions for `/home/test/.ssh` (0700) and `/home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys` (0600)
- I've restarted the SSH service

But when I try to connect to SSH with `test`, it tells me that the `server refused our key`. Please help.

Comment: did you put the public or pvt key in authorized keys?  Depending on the editor, you can also screw up the key.  I often use `cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys` to avoid editor issues.

Comment: @Tyson I copied and pasted the public key given in puttygen.

Comment: I suspect you have an extra invisible character in your file, caused by the paste.

Comment: @Tyson I've looked over it 3 times now and nothing's different. Was I correct in putting the SSH key in `/home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys`? For root I put them in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I've never made one for root, your location for test seems normal tho,  Unless there are weird permissions on '/home/test/' itself making it impossible to see objects below.  Remember that permissions ABOVE any point in the tree may effect permission even tho it *looks* correct at the file/dir level.   Also check ownership.

Comment: @Tyson Every directory up to /home has 755 permissions. What do you mean check ownership?

Comment: In addition to permissions every file has an owner (and groups) go [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-5/), and scroll down to "File ownership and Permissions" and refresh your memory.

Comment: @Tyson That fixed it. I had to change the owner/group of the `.ssh` folder and `authorized_keys` to `test`. Thanks a bunch. (P.S. You should add that as answer so I can mark it as solved) :)

Comment: ssh connection problems are never solved from the client side (it mostly just says "no") but from the server side (look into /var/log/auth.log or the like). 

For security reasons, the server will not provide detailed information on access denials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check for:

No extra characters in authorized_keys. appended or prepended.

Correct permissions 700 for .ssh and 600 for authorized keys.

Correct file ownership, user `test` can't read a file owned by another user or root because of the files permissions.

Comment: Thanks. And for any future viewers, the fix for me was changing the owner of the `.ssh` folder and the `authorized_keys` file to `test` rather than `root`.